# Yii2 Rest Api customize error response

Tags: php, api, rest, yii2

I'm working on a REST API using `Yii2` and I'm trying to customize the `error response`. By default, if I use the wrong credentials when submitting a request I see this:

```
{
    "name": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "You are requesting with an invalid credential.",
    "code": 0,
    "status": 401
}
```

Where and how can I remove the `code` and `name` lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code in your application configuration.

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'response' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
            'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
                $response = $event->sender;
                if ($response->data !== null && Yii::$app->request->get('suppress_response_code')) {
                    $response->data = [
                        'success' => $response->isSuccessful,
                        'data' => $response->data,
                    ];
                    $response->statusCode = 200;
                }
            },
        ],
    ],
];
```

For more [Details](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-error-handling.html#customizing-error-response)

Comment: Thank you.  Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have new solution:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'response' => [
            'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            'charset' => 'UTF-8',
            'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
            'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
                $response = $event->sender;

                // exception with http code != 200 and 302
                if ($response->statusCode !== 200 && $response->statusCode !== 302) {
                    $response->data = [
                        'success' => $response->isSuccessful,
                        'message' => YII_DEBUG ?$response->data: 'System error'
                    ];
                    $response->statusCode = 200;
                }
                // normal response
                else{
                    // both case: controller implement Controller or ActiveController
                    $result =  [
                        'success' => isset($response->data['success'])?$response->data['success']: true
                    ];

                   // check message is set
                if (isset($response->data['message'])){
                    $result = array_merge($result, ['message' => $response->data['message']]);
                }
                else{
                    // check data is set
                    // both case: controller implement Controller or ActiveController
                    if (isset($response->data['data']))
                        $result = array_merge($result, ['data' => $response->data['data']]);
                    else{
                        $result = array_merge($result, ['data' => $response->data]);
                    }
                }

                    $response->data = $result;
                    $response->statusCode = 200;
                }
            },
        ]
    ],
];
```

Comment: How does this improve on the previous answer? Include some explanation to your answer to make it more helpful.